# Como usar Contains sem depender de maiúsculo e minusculo

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Segue o código:

```
var result= db.Table.Where(l => l.Field== value).ToList();

var search = "jOãO pAuLo";
result = result.Where(l => l.Example.Contains(search)).ToList();
```

Só funciona desse jeito: `João Paulo`, se for desse caso `joão Paulo` com letra j minusculo, já não funciona mais.

Alguma solução ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem duas outras alternativas:

1 - Utilizar `ToLower` ou `ToUpper`:

```
result = result.Where(l => l.Example.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())).ToList();

result = result.Where(l => l.Example.ToUpper().Contains(search.ToUpper())).ToList();
```

2 - Utilzar *regex*:

```
result = result.Where(l => Regex.IsMatch(l.Example, search, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)).ToList();
```

Comment: Funcionou aqui utilizando a opção 1.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que a forma mais elegante para resolver isso, eh utilizando um extension Method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var list = new List<String>();
        list.Add("AAAAAO");
        list.Add("BBB");

        list = list.Where(x=> x.Contains("bbb", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();

        Console.WriteLine(list.Count().ToString());

    }

}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool Contains(this string str, string strComparacao, StringComparison argumento)
        {
            return str.IndexOf(strComparacao, argumento) >= 0;
        }
}
```

Comment: É outra alternativa tbm, essa funciona.